# RAID card overwrites disk's filesystem signature - and fstab can't mount it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fstab

I have a RAID card (Sil3124) in an Ubuntu 18.10 machine. I want to connect independent disks (ext4) to it.

After connecting, I find an entry in `lsblk` with `FSTYPE = silicon_medley_raid_member` (the same goes for `blkid`).

Trying to mount, unsurprisingly, results in this error: `mount: /tmp/drive: unknown filesystem type 'silicon_medley_raid_member'.`

Using `wipefs` I see there are two fs signatures on the same disk/partition.

```
DEVICE OFFSET       TYPE                       UUID                                  LABEL
sda    0x45dd825e60 silicon_medley_raid_member                                      
sda    0x438        ext4                       86119597-b945-4dec-a7a5-8cf313f93b40  mydisk
```

If I wipe the "raid" one, `lsblk` recognises the disk normally and I can mount it normally, with my files there as expected. However, when I reboot, the "raid" signature is there again, so I suppose the raid card rewrites it every boot.

The problem is that I want to mount the drive with `fstab`, and while the "raid" signature is there I can't find a way for `fstab` to mount it, as the disk is not findable by UUID or label while the weird signature is there.

The raid card menu is very simple, and I tried all options for single-disk mounts, but the raid signature is always written.

Is there any way to avoid that signature being written, or for fstab to find the "right" signature? If not, is it even possible to run a script pre-fstab to execute wipefs manually (although this feels like a dirty hack)?

Comment: Can you plug the drives in to non-raid ports?

Comment: Unfortunately all motherboard SATA ports are in use (although yes, for testing purposes I have tried and it works normally, provided I wipe the raid signature the first time).

Comment: Why not create partitions on these disks? It appears the RAID signature is at the end of the disk.